# generating results set on server by userId - is this something I should offload to AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My backend stack is basically node (express) and mongo.  Nothing too fancy.

However, I'm generating search and browse page results requests from my client side by userId.  For example, if a user favorites an item, that item is added to a list of favorite itemIds on the back end for that particular user.  So, if the user happens to search for "green scarf" and there's a green scarf that he'd already favorited, the resulting JSON will show this via a `isFavorite: bool`.

Thus, each user will have a different set of data.  The favorites is just one aspect - there are a few other tags as well such as whether a friend has favorited an item, etc.

Is this a use case that warrants offloading to AWS lambda?  The only things I need to do are to connect to my database, execute a query, and return the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from AWS Lambda or not. What I would consider here is using Redis to get the relevant results and tags. You can use Redis in addition to Mongo or you can use Redis only with persistence.

You didn't explain your code in any detail or your load, but if you're getting a lot of those queries that need to check DB to annotate your results for every user then keeping that tags in an in-memory data store can help you with performance no matter if you use AWS Lambda or use a traditional Node process.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I did not include my code here as there's just too much and I'm not sure which bits would be relevant.  But the basic requirement for me is that I need to provide results on a per userId result which is going to require a lot of processing.  If I use redis (something I'm planning on learning next anyway!), would I cache general results (without any userId coupling) and then do a map against those based on specific userId favorites, etc.?  Thanks.  I'm really new to back end (been a front end guy for 1 year, been learning node since Dec) so apologies if I am making you cringe.